# What is the file location of the "blue screen of death"?

Tags: windows, filesystems, bsod

I've always pondered this question but could never find an answer. One of my thoughts was that it was part of the BIOS, but that gets stopped once the kernel can support the system. Than I thought maybe it was part of the Windows kernel, but how can that be if the kernel has crashed? Any thoughts?

Comment: @Alexander: I may have come off wrong. I do know where the minidump and debugging files are stored but the actual code which "is", in essence, the BSoD, I'm unaware of its location. Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 4):

BSOD handling code is in [ntoskrnl.exe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntoskrnl)

Comment: As is most of the core Windows code.

Comment: Formatted text spew to screen from ntoskrnl error handler routine with background color blue and foreground color white. (There is no page &trade; )

Answer (score 0):

Frome [Windows 7 IT Forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/a5ebab26-61ef-42a4-a2bb-0fc60ad45385) theme BSOD error log location:

> Check in `%systemroot%\minidumps` like `c:\windows\minidumps`

See also [Startup and Recovery window](http://blog.nirsoft.net/2010/07/27/how-to-configure-windows-to-create-minidump-files-on-bsod/), "Small dump directory" edit box.

Comment: The OP is *not* asking about the minidump path (see comment above). He apparently thinks there's a separate file for BSODs.